# The native module for Flipper seems unavailable. Please verify that `react-native-flipper` is installed

Tags: react-native, flipper

I have updated React Native from v0.61.4 to v0.62.2 to try and use Flipper.

When I build and run the app The Metro Bundler throws the warning:

> The native module for Flipper seems unavailable. Please verify that `react-native-flipper` is installed as yarn dependency to your project and, for iOS, that `pod install` is run in the `ios` directory.

I have installed it using npm.

My package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.45.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-flipper": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
 ...
```

In Flipper, React DevTools can connect to the app but when I try to use the Hermes Debugger or plugins they cannot be used:

[image]
[image]

When I run this:
`adb shell am start -n com.app/com.facebook.flipper.android.diagnostics.FlipperDiagnosticActivity`

I get this error:

> Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.app/com.facebook.flipper.android.diagnostics.FlipperDiagnosticActivity} does not exist.

What could be the reason for the modules not installing correctly?

Comment: I have the same issue, some find their solution here: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1253, give it a try ;)